# How does Superposition principle follow from Maxwell's equation's linearity?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, maxwell-equations, superposition, linear-systems

It is said that whole of electromagnetism can be completely described by the Maxwell's equations.

The thing that intrigues me is that how does superposition principle follow?
First, I take an example, where $2$ charges $q_i$ are placed at a distance $d_i$ from a point, $i=1,2$. Now to calculate the field at that at point, we simply add the electric field due to individual charges at that point if the other charge was not there (Field calculated using Gauss' law). But how do we know that now, after the charges are placed **together**, the electric field due to both of them there is unaffected and also, that it adds up?

**Edit:** For all those who are saying that since Gauss' Law is a linear equation, that is why the SP follows. Please read the question again. I am asking the reasoning behind it, *why* SP follows from linearity (Or how).

It would be appreciated if someone explains it in the simple example I chose above. (2 point charges)

Comment: Ignoring constant factors, Gauss' law is $\nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \rho$. So if both $\nabla \cdot \mathbf E_1 = \rho_1$ and $\nabla \cdot \mathbf E_2 = \rho_2$ are solutions, then by the linearity of Gauss' law $\nabla \cdot \mathbf (\mathbf E_1+\mathbf E_2) = (\rho_1+\rho_2)$ is also a solution.

Comment: @CuspyCode, in case of point charges, the above equations become a bit unclear. So lets use integral forms for the sake of simplicity. Now for both, individually, the equations hold (in absence of any other charges). But when they are placed together, how do they add up? How does the field at the point follow from Gauss' Law?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, are you really asking how to use Gauss' flux law to calculate E using a Gaussian surface?  If so this is neither practical or logical.  The failure to be able to do this does not negate the principle of superposition.  This could be a cause of confusion.

Comment: In the above I meant E total, not simply E.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, with all due respect I refer you to my answer.  You edit doesn't change anything.  I am explaining how SP follows from linearity, the proof is almost trivial.  What I offer is a generalization of Cuspy Code's original comment.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Maybe you should explain what you mean by "superposition principle"? Because using the conventional meaning this principle is a mathematically trivial consequence of linearity. But I suspect you have something different in mind. Are you considering interactions between your two point particles, in addition to their contributions to the total E field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply superposition does NOT follow from Maxwell's equations.  It is a mathematical principle and it holds for any linear equation or system of equations.  Maxwell's equations are just one of many that fall into this category.  The general form is:

D(Field) = Source

where D() is some abstract differential linear operator.  Linearity means that if F1 is a solution for S1, and F2 is a solution for S2 then F1 + F2 is a solution for S1 + S2.  The proof can be found in most math texts on ordinary or partial differential equations, also linear algebra or operator theory.  Once you "prove" that a set of equations is in fact linear you can immediately apply this result.

You state using Gauss' law to calculate the field.  The more fundamental equation is Coulomb's law, which was discovered as an empirical law, along with its linearity, by experiments conducted by Coulomb.  This is how we know that the field behaved linearly.  When we learn all this physics today we sometime forget the history, how our knowledge is connected to history, and what comes first (i.e. what piece of knowledge is fundamental rather than derived).

Comment: Regarding your final part, I agree that history is fundamental. But finally, when the theory is established, then we kind of *forget* the history. I am told that the most fundamental thing in electromagnetism is the Maxwell's equations, not the Coulomb's law. (Whole of electromagnetism can be described using these 4 equations, and nowhere, the need of superposition principle is needed.)

Comment: Now as far as the linearity part is concerned. Can you explain it in the context of the example **I** used? Like, the field of $q_1$ at point in absence of all other charges, by Gauss Law equation, is say $E_1$ and similarly for $q_2$. But when both are placed at a finite distance from each other, how do we know that the fields (the ones which were calculated in absence of each other) would be added up?

Comment: (1) Maxwell's equations might be proved wrong some day but whatever replaces them better give Coulomb's law, (2) "...electromagnetism can be described using these 4..." is true, but "...and nowhere, the need of superposition principle is needed..." is both wrong and misleading.  Maxwell's equations are in fact linear therefore the "superposition principle" is ensured (not needed).

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, I am not sure how to address your second comment as I think you are not reading my answer.  You seem to be using "Gauss' Law" as a motivation to find E and that's okay but again, this equation in both differential and integral form is mathematically linear hence superposition is ensured.  In my answer q1 and q2 would be source1 and source2, etc.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, another way to look at things, from a PDE theory perspective, is that Coulomb's law is proportional to the Green's function of the field equation, e.g. solution for a Dirac delta distribution = point source.  From the general theory the result for an arbitrary distribution is the integral of Green's function over the source distribution which is once again the principle of linear superposition.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Maxwell's equations is not the most fundamental part of electromagnetism because it is a classical field theory. They are fine as long as you are in the classical regime, but quantum corrections are explained by quantum electrodynamics. And in a very high electric field, electromagnetism becomes nonlinear, see for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit

Comment: The apparent non-linearity you are referring to is due to the interaction of EM with Matter, via pair production.  The quantum theory of both is linear, w/o linearity we wouldn't be able to put together the equations and Feynman diagrams to describe the interactions.  It is a type of macro effect like the one discussed by GiorgioP.

Comment: @ggcg Interactions *mean* nonlinearity. That's precisely why Feynman diagrams are used in the first place. Using Feynman diagrams in a theory that is linear in some field is overkill.

Comment: @Avantgarde Interactions do not necessarily mean nonlinearity, that is not a requirement.  The field equations with sources are still linear, they are just more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Superposition principle (SP) holds for every physical phenomenon which may be modeled by linear equations.

A frequently neglected consequence is that, in the case of macroscopic electromagnetic fields, SP is not unconditionally true, even if Maxwell's equations are linear, due to the completely general (non-linear) relation between the fields $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{D}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{H}$. It is only in the cases of vacuum and linear materials that the full set of Maxwell's equations **and** [constitutive equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutive_equation#Without_magnetic_or_dielectric_materials) is globally linear and SP holds.

Comment: So it should be mentioned that Electromagnetism is described by Maxwell's equations, and the superposition principle,  not just the Maxwell's equations? That is what my question finally points out.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Not completely true. If one would like to look at the EM in the vacuum as a fundamental theory,the constitutive equations are linear and the whole set of equations (Maxwell's equations + contitutive equations) is linear. Thus, superposition pronciple holds. But if one is dealing with macroscopic fields, its important to recall that in general constitutive equations are not linear (for example it is not linear the relation between $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ in the case of a permanent magnet).

Comment: In those  cases, superposition principle doesn't hold even if Mxwell's equations are linear in the four fields.

Comment: @GiorgioP, the non-linearity you are referring is duel, presumably to some average coupling between elements to generate a macro effect, as in non-linear optical phenomenon and second harmonic generation in non-linear crystals?  Good point +1.

Comment: @ggcg Yes, the non-linearity enters into play as soon as one has to consider macroscopic fields, which may be obtained by averaging the microscopic fields. Non-linear induction effects destroy the linearity of the equations.

Comment: Exactly, the fundamental process is still linear, but the macro behavior cannot likely be determined by analyzing the micro processes.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's equations did not answer all electromagnetic theory. Actually Maxwell equation + Lorenz gauge + superposition principle together solve the current electromagnetic problems. Hence superposition principle is an independent principle. It is not included in Maxwell's theory.

Lorenz gauge is very important. Lorenz gauge is a correct gauge. Maxwell uses the Coulomb gauge. That is a wrong gauge. Hence in order to solve the electromagnetic problem, Lorenz gauge is required. Lorenz gauge should be as 5th Maxwell equations. (Here is Lorenz not Lorentz). Lorenz introduced Lorenz gauge in 1867. Only a few years later than Maxwell's theory. He also introduced retarded potential in the same paper. The concept of retarded potential is equivalent to the displacement current of Maxwell. Lorenz introduce the retarded potential is base on his study in optic and elastic wave. Hence Lorenz should get the respect similar to Maxwell.

As I know the suppositions of the static field electric field and static electric magnetic field is self-explained. However it is difficult to prove the radiation field can be superposed.

For radiation fields, there are two kind of fields retarded potential and advanced potential. They are the solutions of Maxwell equations. As I know the transmitting antenna sent retarded wave. The receiving antenna sends the advanced wave. Most scientists do not accept the advanced wave because of the causality problem. However the absorber theory of Wheeler and Feynman, Transactional interpretation of John Cramer supports the advanced wave. The mutual energy flow theorem also supports the advanced wave. We know there is current in the receiving antenna when it receives wireless waves. This current should produce some wave, if this wave is retarded wave, the receiving antenna actually is a transmitting antenna but not a receiving antenna. Hence the advanced wave should exist. Can the retarded wave and advanced wave be supposed? This is not clear.

Radiation is a very complicated phenomena, our today's theory still does not answer the problem of wave-particle duality problem. Wave can be supposed, but it is clear that the particle cannot be supposed.

Feynman and his doctor father Wheeler tell us if the space is empty, the sun cannot shine. In order to let the sun shine there needs the absorbers. Our current electromagnetic field theory (Maxwell theory) did not reflect this point of view. This means something is wrong in classical electromagnetic field theory. If something is wrong we first need to test whether or not the superposition principle is correct. There are some publications that tell us the supposition principle is correct at 15%, (I forget the cite place). Anyway superposition principle is not tested like Coulomb's law.

There is the concept of wave collapse. The wave collapse process if it exists should be some kind of waves. As I know the wave collapse is related to the concept of time-reversal waves.  Can this kind wave be supposed? It is not clear.

Summary: Maxwell theory is not a complete theory (Otherwise do not need QET), superposition principle should be an independent principle to Maxwell equations. It needs to be tested again and again in case there is some new theory developed in electromagnetic field theory or quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

First, superposition principle and linearity is the same thing, exactly how @Cuspy Code wrote in a comment above.

The answer to *why* you could add electric fields in the first place, or more precisely, *what* causes the equations of motion to become *linear* (instead of something else random), comes from symmetry. Interactions in a theory are mediated by [gauge fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory). In [quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics)(QED), there is one gauge field called the photon and is denoted by $A_\mu$. The key point is that the local symmetry group in QED, which is [U(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group), is *[Abelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group)*. You can change the order of 2 successive gauge transformations without changing anything. The resulting equations of motion are linear in $A_\mu$: there are no self-interaction terms. If the local symmetry was non-Abelian, you would get self-interactions between the gauge fields, as happens for gluons that describe the strong nuclear force in [quantum chromodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics). In general relativity (GR) too, there are graviton self-interactions. So although for many purposes you can add Newtonian potentials, we really should be taking the non-linearities into account. The non-linear structure of GR explains Mercury's perihelion precession, for instance; see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/424779/133418).

But in all this analysis, it must be noted that we considered an idealized situation where the sources are fixed. In reality, everything is affected by everything else and all backreaction effects (which cause non-linearity) must be taken into account in order to be as precise as possible.

Comment: Linearity does not come from symmetry.  One can easily have non-linear equations with symmetry.  How else do you explain non-abelian gauge theories or general relativity?  This answer is misleading -1.

Comment: @ggcg You misunderstood the point I was making. I did not state that GR or non-Abelian gauge theories don't have symmetries. That is (untrue and) tangential from the point I was making. It's not about the 'presence' or 'absence' of a symmetry, but *what* it is, exactly. That makes ALL the difference, to the physics of any theory. To be pedantic, the answer comes from the fact that the gauge group is Abelian.

Comment: You statement is simply untrue.  Linearity does not in any way come from an abelian gauge symmetry.  There are plenty of non-gauge theories that are linear.

Comment: Like, any and every linear equation.  Linearity is an older concept than gauge theory and does not require a gauge group to exist.  Conversely non-linear theories can have gauge symmetry.  The two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @ggcg Of the 4 forces in the universe, which one is not described by a gauge theory? Exclude gravity for a moment, which has general coordinate invariance.

Comment: We are not talking about fundamental forces we are talking about a general principle of mathematics.  Acoustics is one example.  This conversation is tedious.  You are making a connection between things that does not exist by appealing to false arguments.  Linearity exists independently of gauge symmetry.  The fact that the 4 fundamental forces can be expressed a a guage field has no bearing on that.  And some of them and both symmetric and non-linear.

Comment: @ggcg The historical timeline of which concepts were discovered when has nothing to do with the laws of the universe. And no, we are not talking about the mathematics of linear algebra here. The question is about a physical theory and about *why* the equations are linear. What tells you to add 2 electric fields instead of multiplying them, or anything else? Where do you think it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

After a few comments and the last edit of the original question, I think that the original question has been better focused and it is more a question about how to prove SP for linear electrodynamics (Maxwell's equations plus linear constitutive equations) using Gauss' law in the integral form.

Answer to this question is that it cannot be done at the same level of simplicity one is able to derive Coulomb's low from Gauss' law. Indeed, in the case of Coulomb's law, one exploits heavily  the symmetry of the field due to a point-like charge. The symmetry allows to obtain from a unique number (the flux through the surface of a sphere with the charge at the centre) the value of the electric field at all the points on the spherical surface.

Missing the simplification offered by symmetry, Gauss' law is not able to provide directly the electric field at one point. It can be done indirectly by using  the integral form to derive the differential form and the differential form of Gauss'law **plus** the condition on the curl of $\mathbf{E}$ and the boundary conditions allow to get the value of electric field everywhere.

As far as the derivation of SP from Maxwell's equations in differential form, it is basically contained in the first comment by Cuspy Code.

Comment: So, this sounds like a completely new question.  Any maybe should be one, closing this.  Linearity exists in Gauss' flux law.  In fact this is what makes flux calculation possible when there is no symmetry!!  But that is derived from other laws, SP is not derived from it.